# FullPage.js Normal scroll with horizontal slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, fullpage.js

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html#secondPage/1

Hi, in this example, is it possible

- To lose the auto scroll that automatically comes, whenever i reach in between a page?
- The horizontal slider doesn't work on arrow press/swipe motion.

  ```
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
          menu: '#menu',
          anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage'],
          sectionsColor: ['#C63D0F', '#1BBC9B', '#7E8F7C'],
          autoScrolling: false
      });
  ```

**Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwde78ts/11/)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To lose the auto scroll that automatically comes, whenever i reach in between a page?

Yeah. Use the fullpage.js option `fitToSection:false`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwde78ts/17/)

> The horizontal slider doesn't work on arrow press/swipe motion.

No idea what you mean with `arrow motion`. Clicking on the arrows work as expected.

Comment: Clicking on the arrows works yes, but not right and left keyboard button presses which usually works. [Also would that work on swipe ?]

Comment: There's no way to disable only one direction with keyboard. I'll probably add it in future versions.

Comment: What i meant was, scrolling horizontally using the left and right arrow keys [scrolling the slides, not the sections. ]

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK sorry I misunderstood your comments. The answer still being **no**. The keyboard arrows will work like in any normal site when using `autoScrolling:false`. This was a design decision taken when disable the keyboard to scroll through sections when `autoScrolling:false`.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK nevertheless, you can still linking any event (such as the key press) to any fullPage.js function. Take a look at [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29822757/1081396).

Comment: I will take a look, have a doubt though on which all slides under which sections will go right/left when that moveSlideRight function is called though.
Will try and get back to you.

Comment: Only the active section (which will be the one in the viewport or with the biggest part of it in it) will react to the `moveSlideRight` or `moveSlideLeft` events.

If you find the question answered, please accept the answer so it can b useful for other people ending up in this question.

Comment: alvaro, one more final doubt. 
If am using the $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all') function, should i use reBuild or call fullpage function again?

Comment: initialize fullPage.js again.