# Fullpage.js - Vertical Scroll with Keyboard

Tags: javascript, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js, vertical-scrolling

I am hoping someone can help me with my issue below.

I am using Fullpage.js (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) plugin to create a site where pages move horizontally. The plugin is designed to create full page sites where it vertically scrolls through each section, by scrolling or pressing down the keys, just like a parallax site.

In my file,  I am only using the one section with left and right arrows to contain my multiple pages for horizontal scrolling. Like the example on http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html Since I don't have multiple sections, when I hit the up/down keys it doesn't scroll the content at all.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the fullpage functions `moveSlideRight` and `moveSlideLeft` to your keydown events and turn off the default keyboard scrolling of fullpage.js by using `$.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false)`

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var shiftPressed = e.shiftKey;

    switch (e.which) {
        //up
        case 38:
        case 33:
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();
            break;

        //down
        case 40:
        case 34:
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            break;

    }
});
```

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/560/)